# change textSize of each row on runtime while scrolling listview

Tags: android, listview, uiscrollview

I have used a custom base adapter. I am trying to achieve telescopic view in list. I have an infinite listview.

```
 ArrayList<String> months=new ArrayList<>();
    months.add("January");
    months.add("February");
    months.add("March");
    months.add("April");
    months.add("May");
    months.add("June");
    months.add("July");
    months.add("August");
    months.add("September");
    months.add("October");
    months.add("November");
    months.add("December");

    CircularListAdapter circularListAdapter=new CircularListAdapter(new CircularBaseAdapterDatePickerMonth(getActivity(),months));

    monthList.setAdapter(circularListAdapter);


    monthList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == 0) {




            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            int firstVisibleRow=monthList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int lastVisibleRow=monthList.getLastVisiblePosition();

        }
    });


    return view;

}
```

above is my main code
below is my adapter

```
/**
 * Created by user4 on 07-05-2016.
 */
public class CircularBaseAdapterDatePickerMonth extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<String> items;

    public CircularBaseAdapterDatePickerMonth(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {

        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MyviewHolder myviewHolder;
        if (convertView != null) {
            myviewHolder = (MyviewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            myviewHolder = new MyviewHolder();
            convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_date_picker_dialog_list_text, parent, false);
            myviewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Onboarding_DateDialog_List_text);
            convertView.setTag(myviewHolder);
        }

        myviewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class MyviewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```

I am not sure about the `onScrollListener()` too, whether it will help me or not.